# Ng-Repeat showing irregular behavior with one time binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

I am having a ng-repeat directive that is running on the array on object. I am facing a specific scenario in which, When I Bind my object properties with one time binding they are now getting refreshed when I Purge and add the data in my Array Of Object on which I am running my ng-repeat.

The point to focus here is, All these functionalities were working previosuly.

**CODE**

```
<div class="search_result" data-ng-repeat="prod in searchResult track by $index" ng-show="ShowWhenResultPositive">
    <div class="media search-result-container">
        <div class="media-left">
            <div class="left ">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="leftBottom">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="rightTop">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="rightBottom">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="searchimg_container" ng-click="redirectionToPage(prod.url)">
                <!--<img src="{{prod.tkh_imageurl}}"  alt="Not Available" class="lazyload"/>-->
                <picture>
                    <source data-srcset="{{prod.desktopImage}}" media="(min-width: 768px)">
                    <source data-srcset="{{prod.mobileImage}}" media="(min-width: 320px)">
                    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-src="${properties.placeholderimage}" alt="Not Available" class="lazyload"><!--${properties.placeholderimage}-->
                </picture>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body search-desc">
            <p ng-if="isPDF" class="subheading" ng-click="redirectionToPage(prod.url)">{{::prod.title}}</p>
            <p ng-if="!isPDF" class="subheading" ng-click="redirectionToPage(prod.url)">{{::prod.tkh_title}}</p>
            <p ng-if="!isPDF" class="resultdesc">{{::prod.tkh_description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the same.

Comment: Please post a plunker or fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Docs:

> Avoid using `track by $index` when the repeated template contains [one-time bindings](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding). In such cases, the `nth` DOM element will always be matched with the `nth` item of the array, so the bindings on that element will not be updated even when the corresponding item changes, essentially causing the view to get out-of-sync with the underlying data.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-repeat API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

If you are working with objects that have a **unique identifier property, you should track by this identifier** instead of the object instance. Should you reload your data later, `ngRepeat` will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones. For large collections, this significantly improves rendering performance.